# What is the scope of the @SuppressStaticInitializationFor PowerMock annotation?

Tags: junit, powermock

Does anyone know what is the scope of this annotation? For example, if I have multiple JUnit test classes that run sequentially in the same VM, and the first test uses @SuppressStaticInitializationFor, does that suppress the static initialization for all the subsequent test classes, too? I ask because I am under the impression that static state persists for the life of the JVM.

Answer (score 3):

The scope is per classloader. Once you've used @SuppressStaticInitializationFor it'll affect the class in all other tests. You can however @SuppressStaticInitializationFor at the method level instead and that way it won't affect other tests.

Comment: I don't have a strong understand of classloaders, but my impression is that, under typical circumstances, a given class is loaded exactly once per JVM, when it is first accessed. This leads me to conclude that, under typical circumstances, the scope of @SuppressStaticInitializationFor is the JVM instance.

Comment: I didn't know you could use @SuppressStaticInitializationFor at the method level. Would you happen to have a reference for that? After a moderate amount of Googling I have not seen it used like that before. Also, would you happen to know how it works at the method level? If the scope of the annotation is per classloader, then couldn't it affect other test methods?

Answer (score 0):

you can use @SuppressStaticInitializationFor annotation at the class-level or at the method-level of the test where you want it to be suppressed.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.main.java.CassName")
public class TestClassName extends PowerMockTestCase {
    //code
    @SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.main.java.AnotherClassName")
    public void testMethod() {
        //code
    }
}
```

This way you can control which method should suppress static initializers(constructors) and for which class.